# QGIS 3x apply one data attribute table for more than 1 layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have got a few layers, in which the data attribute table looks exactly the same including:

- Type (string)
- Address (string)
- Postcode (string)
- X (East) (decimal)
- Y (north (decimal)
- Latitude (decimal)
- Longitude (decimal)
- ObjectID (string)
- length (meters) (decimal)

I have to create them every time for every single layer. Is there any way to make them loaded instantly as a blank data attribute table for the layer I want?

Comment: Are you creating the features later on, or do you just fill in the "blanks"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute the following code in the QGIS Python console to create a table and add it to the QGIS project.

For the example, this is a **temporary** layer with a **Polygon** geometry which will be called **layer_name**.

```
your_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "layer_name", "memory")
prov = your_layer.dataProvider()

prov.addAttributes([QgsField("Type", QVariant.String),
QgsField("Address",  QVariant.String),
QgsField("Postcode", QVariant.String),
QgsField("X", QVariant.Double),
QgsField("Y", QVariant.Double),
QgsField("Latitude", QVariant.Double),
QgsField("Longitude", QVariant.Double),
QgsField("ObjectID", QVariant.String),
QgsField("Length", QVariant.Double)])


your_layer.updateFields()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(your_layer)
```

Comment: It's fine, but this code creates a separate layer for me. I have got existing layers already.

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to a small python script, here you go:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsField
from qgis.utils import iface

x = 20
y = 2

attributes = [QgsField("Type", QVariant.String, len=x),
              QgsField("Address", QVariant.String, len=x),
              QgsField("Postcode", QVariant.String, len=x),
              QgsField("X", QVariant.Double, len=x, prec=y),
              QgsField("Y", QVariant.Double, len=x, prec=y),
              QgsField("Latitude", QVariant.Double, len=x, prec=y),
              QgsField("Longitude", QVariant.Double, len=x, prec=y),
              QgsField("ObjectID", QVariant.Double, len=x, prec=y),
              QgsField("length", QVariant.Double, len=x, prec=y)]

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(attributes)
layer.updateFields()
```

edit:
PS : `iface.activeLayer()` gets the selected layer from the legend

Comment: Could also be done by a model incorporating `refactor fields`, but neither would be necessary, if @MKR creates the layer from scratch, then he'd simply create an empty template and copy it.

Comment: @Erik i answer with this because it works both for new layers and layers with fields already, sure there are better way to do this but i think that's enought. especially if you just want to add a few attributes on the fly